# change state based on scroll position on ie

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer

I need to add or remove a class to a div by scroll position. so I added a listener to document scroll event to change state

```
componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('scroll', function (event) {
      const isPassedTop = window.pageYOffset  > 100;
      if (isPassedTop !== this.state.isPassedTop) {
        this.setState({ isPassedTop: isPassedTop })
      }
    }, true);
}
```

this code is working on chrome but on ie it says Object doesn't support property or method 'setState'
I can use jquery to add or remove a class there but I'm looking to a way to do it by state.
anybody has idea how to do it on cross browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do it would be to create a bound function so that you can refer to it later to remove the listener on unmount, something like this:

```js
class Foo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleScrollChange = this.handleScrollChange.bind(this);
  }    

  handleScrollChange() {
    const isPassedTop = window.pageYOffset  > 100;
    if (isPassedTop !== this.state.isPassedTop) {
      this.setState({ isPassedTop: isPassedTop })
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScrollChange, true);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScrollChange);
  }
}
```